# Migrate java web project IBM RAD to Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, websphere, ibm-rad, migrating

We have a project that developed in IBM RAD 8.5 and using WebSphere Server.
I want to migrate the project to Intellij idea and use tomcat to jBos for server.
When I try to add the dependencies jars, still I got this error.
"Error:(14, 36) java: unmappable character (0xE7) for encoding UTF-8"

I think I am missing something huge. Could you please explain me what is the trick under the hood of migrating. I have .classpath, .project web.xml, build.xml. How to edit them to get completely free from RAD.

regards

Comment: Could you please clarify at what step do you get error? While adding dependency or while running application?

Comment: If you want to migrate from WebSphere to open source, then better migrate to Open Liberty, which is free but still WebSphere. It is much better choice than Tomcat or JBoss.